# Knowing what ciphers your users are using

Tags: iis, logging, rc4-cipher, schannel

I need to know if many people are on my site with a browser using RC4. The main culprits being IE6,7,8 on XP.

Apparently by [enabling SChannel](http://www.alexwho.com/blog/2009/10/increase-schannel-logging.html) logging I can do this and then read the results in the event log.

To test I have enabled SChannel Logging on my test server but I can't see where in the event viewer I should be able to see any of the info this new logging provides.

The test server is using a self-signed cert and I've accessed it using IE7 on a 'secure' page, but there's nothing in the event logs, or at least nothing I can see.

Does anyone know where I should be looking to see what cipher the user is using?

Comment: You did not say which server does the https processing for your site. I assume it is iis, but which version?

Comment: Sorry, it is IIS 8

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use nets trace command to log and later open the ETL file with Windows Performance Analyzer or NetMon, sources from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/531830/logging-ssl-ciphersuite-used-in-windows-server-2008-r2#531834) and [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299520).
Regarding your self signed certificate I advice you to get a free public certificate from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org). I hope my answer solves your problem, best regards Gillsoft AB.

```
netsh trace start capture=yes
```

Comment: Surely though the fact that I've enabled extra SChannel logging should mean that it is recorded somewhere in the event viewer. Certainly all the documentation says it does, the problem is finding where in the event viewer I can see this though.

Comment: You will still have the problem to connect Channel logs with to corresponding IIS log info for that request (to get useful information), that's why I suggested a solution that will give you all this in one go.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is essentially as much as you can do, apart from capturing and filtering the HTTPS packets.

To what level did you bump your SChannel loggin? According to the [official MS page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260729) the best for you would be 0x0007 (i.e., 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x0004). The log messages themselves should be in the System event log.

Comment: Thanks, I bumped it to 0x0003, but can change it again to 7 and see. I've been looking in the system event log but have not seen anything yet,